# why does "program not responding" freeze shut down on one machine but not on another?

Tags: windows-xp, shutdown, freeze

I often get "program not responding" issue on my Windows XP Pro machines during shut down. However, one machine just ignores it and shuts down. But the other essentially freezes until I manually say "end task", and that is very inconvenient.

Is this a known issue? Is this a matter of user specified OS settings, or hardware peculiarities or basically why would something like that happen?

Comment: I believe this question is more suited for serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is configurable via a registry setting.

- Go to **Start -> Run** and type **regedit** in the box then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Expand the treeview to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
```

If the value **AutoEndTasks** isn't there already, you can create it. It should be a string value (REG_SZ).

- Setting it to 0 will disable it (tasks will have to be ended manually)
- Setting it to 1 will enable it (it will automatically end the programs for you)